# Try to find face detection using opencv harcascade file but the x,y,w,h values are empty

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

Try to find face detection using opencv harcascade file but the x,y,w,h values are empty

```
import cv2            ***import packages***
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')    **import 
                                                                                 haarcascade**
image=cv2.imread("messi.jpg")     **read image**
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   **convert gray image**
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2)
        
cv2.imshow("crop/region of interset image",image) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

can it be that no faces are detected in the picture at all (and therefore, the loop doesn't even run)?
I would suggest to print the length of faces first, to verify that.

Comment: when i print the values x,y,w,h its with no value but when change the value of detect MultiScale  [1.3 to 1.1,5 to 4]it print the value

Answer (score 0):

This normally should not happen. I also made a face recognition haar cascade classifier with python and opencv. Are you sure that there are no errors in the training data? For example, stages are deleted or stage 10 is there and 12 is there but stage 11 is not there. I think these are the only way this can Happen. If this is the problem, delete your training data and train it again. My guess is that you just re-train your model. REMEMBER: Delete everything including your stages, training data your model before you start training your model again.